# Passing buttons to new objects then adding to itself again?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jbutton

I have tried to compile the program and it really does not like these lines:

```
Listener l1 = new Listener(button2);
Listener l2 = new Listener(button1);

button1.addActionListener(l1);
button2.addActionListener(l2);
```

I am a bit confused as to what is going on. I looked in my Oracle Java book and they just offer simple example when handling buttons and listeners.

I am really confused as to what as supposed to happening when someone pushed button1 one time then a second time then button2?

To me it looks like a button1 and button2 type CS12Button are being passed as a variable type to a class Listener with variable 11 and 12. Then finally being added to button1 again?  Back to itself?

```
public class ExamQuestion1 extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ExamQuestion1 eq1 = new ExamQuestion1();
        eq1.init();

        eq1.pack();
        eq1.setVisible(true);
        eq1.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        eq1.repaint();
    }

    private void init(){
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button1 = new JButton("one");
        CS12Button button2 = new CS12Button("two");
        CS12Button button3 = new CS12Button("three");

        Listener l1 = new Listener(button2);
        Listener l2 = new Listener(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(l1);
        button2.addActionListener(l2);

        contentPane.add(button1);
        contentPane.add(button2);
        contentPane.add(button3);

        JTextField jt = new JTextField(10);
        contentPane.add(jt);
        jt.setText("File name here");

        //CS12Panel cp = new CS12Panel();
        //contentPane.add(cp);


        //public int[] readList(String filename);


    }

}
```

Comment: What's `Listener`? And it's not `11` and `12` it's `L1` and `L2` (lower case "L")

Comment: also, what do you mean by the "it really does not like these lines"? Does it compiles? Does it throw exceptions on execution? Does it behave incorrectly?